# Update query is not working. Table data isn't changing

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Mysql update query isn't working. Table data isn't changing. I use MySql and C#. My table fields are:

```
username,
password,
name,
Loggedin
```

Code:

```
try
{
    string userlogout = "UPDATE  UsersTable SET Loggedin = '0'   WHERE username = '" + txtlogoutusername.Text+ "' ";
    obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;
    obj.cmd.CommandText = userlogout;
    obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    userpanel.Visible = false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
}
```

Comment: `int rows = obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` will tell you how many rows were affected.  then we can provide some guidance

Comment: First, learn ASAP how to use parameterized queries to avoid Sql Injection. Then get the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. If it is zero this means that your query doesn't find any user with that username

Comment: @steve i have select queries to display loggedin users. when a user logout this code block should run.

Comment: @plutonix ; it says 0 rows affected.

Comment: As Steve indicated, that means there is no record matching that name.  Use parameters always - that has not been the correct way to build SQL for a long time; also DBConnections ought to be created, used and disposed as needed - that code looks like it is trying to reuse the same one; the same is doubly true of a DBCommand object.

Answer (score 1):

Connection String on App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="con_str" connectionString="~~~~~your connection string~~~~~~~~~~~"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

check your select statement

```
string myconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con_str"].ConnectionString;



    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
        try
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE UsersTable SET Loggedin = '0' WHERE username = @userName";              
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);          
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtlogoutusername.Text);
            conn.Open();
            int rowsAffected =cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("rows affected: " + rowsAffected);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```